# Vaadin - set focus in Login Page

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I am using the login form to log in to the app. I need to set the Focus after starting the application to the Password field. I can only set a description through the getFrom method.

```
LoginI18n i18n = LoginI18n.createDefault();
    i18n.setHeader(new LoginI18n.Header());
    i18n.getHeader().setTitle("ACB");
    i18n.getHeader().setDescription("Login use user/user or admin/admin");
    i18n.setAdditionalInformation(null);
    i18n.getForm().setTitle("Login");
    i18n.getForm().setPassword("Pass");
    i18n.getForm().setUsername("User");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some JavaScript:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage()
    .executeJs("document.getElementById('vaadinLoginUsername').focus();");
```

Comment: Does not work for the Password field.

Comment: Oh sorry. It's vaadinLoginPassword in that case

Comment: yes, works    UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("document.getElementById('vaadinLoginPassword').focus();");